# Formatting Data Prior to Submit

Tags: php, jquery

I am using PHP to run a SQL command that ultimately updates a table. Right now I am using the maskedinput.js plugin to format phone numbers using the following format: `(999) 999-9999`.

What I am wanting to do is, prior to the submit from occurring, is format the telephones back to nothing but digits. So naturally, I thought that I would handle the on submit event of the form and then use RegEx to set the inputs' value back to only digits. However, the on submit event never gets fired.

I have tried setting the `onsubmit` attribute of the `form` element to a function like the following:

```
<form id="update_business" method="post" onsubmit="format()" action="assets/php/update_business.php">
```

...but that never gets fired. So, I have tried setting up the on submit jQuery function like the following:

```
$('#update_business').on('submit', function(e) {...});
```

... but it didn't fire either. So, I have tried setting up the event handler thru the document first like the following:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#update_business', function(e) {...});
```

... but it didn't fire either! At this point I have search countless stackoverflow posts on why the event never fires, but I cannot find anything that solves my issue.

**UPDATE**

The markup for my submit button is:

`<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>`

**UPDATE #2**

The markup for my form when implementing Abdulla Nilam's suggestion:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  // format the phone numbers
  $('input[type="tel"]').mask('(999) 999-9999');
  // setup the toolbar that the richtext editor will use
  var toolbar = [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],        // toggled buttons
    ['blockquote'],

    [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }],                         // text direction

    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],  // custom dropdown
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
    [ 'link', 'image', 'video', 'formula' ],
    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],          // dropdown with defaults from theme
    [{ 'font': [] }],
    [{ 'align': [] }],

    ['clean']                                         // remove formatting button
  ];
  // setup the rich text editor for the signature
  var editor = new Quill('#signature', {
    modules: {
      formula: true,
      syntax: true,
      container: '#signature.toolbar-container',
      toolbar: toolbar
    },
    placeholder: 'signature',
    theme: 'snow'
  });
  // form submission
  function onSubmit( form ){
    var data = JSON.stringify( $(form).serializeArray() );

    console.log( data );
    return false; //don't submit
  }
  $('#update_business').submit(function() {
    alert('here');
    return true; // Must
  });
  /*$('#update_business').submit(function() {
    // remove any non-digits from the telephone inputs
    $('input[type="tel"]').text(function(index, text){return text.replace(/^D/, '');});
    // set the text of the hidden signature field
    $('#hidden_signature').text(editor.root.innerHTML);

    return true;
  });*/
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.5/quill.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.5/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form id="update_business" method="post" action="assets/php/update_business.php">
  <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="return_url" required="required" value="profile.php" />
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Business Information</legend>
    <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="business_id" required="required" id="business_id" value="<?php echo $profile->business_id; ?>" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="business_name">Business Name</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="business_name" required="required" id="business_name" value="<?php echo $profile->name; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="phone" required="required" id="phone" value="<?php echo $profile->phone; ?>" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="fax">Fax Number</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="tel" name="fax" required="required" id="fax" value="<?php echo $profile->fax; ?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Address Information</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="address">Address</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" required="required" id="address" value="<?php echo $profile->address; ?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="city">City</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" required="required" id="city" value="<?php echo $profile->city_name; ?>" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="state">State</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="state" id="state">
          <?php 
            $states = include('assets/php/get_states.php');
            foreach ($states as &$state) {
              echo '<option value="' . $state['state_id'] . '"' . ($state['abbreviation'] == $profile->abbreviation ? 'selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . $state['abbreviation'] . "</option>\n";
            }
          ?>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label for="zip">Zip Code</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="zip" required="" pattern="\d{5}" id="zip" value="<?php echo $profile->code; ?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Signature</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Signature</label>
      <div class="form-control" aria-describedby="signature_help" id="signature" style="min-height: 25rem;">
        <div class="toolbar-container"></div>
        <div class="editor-container h-25"></div>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="signature" id="hidden_signature" />
      <small id="signature_help" class="form-text text-muted">Signatures are not updated immediately, instead they must first be approved for compliance.</small>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: No Javascript error on the page ?

Comment: have you debugged the code in browser or using debugger?

Comment: Also (on a slightly different topic), the formatting for this should preferably be done on the server (php) side using something like `$variable = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $variable);` ... because, if you had to submit the data from another client type, like an API or a mobile app, the logic is best keep in one place to prevent duplication.

Comment: Just fyi, HTML5 supports the [pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_input_pattern.asp) attribute on inputs

Comment: @Syscall - Whenever I use the onsubmit method, I get the error "format is not defined", even though I create the function in my document ready event.

Comment: @swetanshkumar - yes.

Comment: @kerbholz - I'm aware, however if you read the first sentence, you'll see that I'm formatting the textbox to something other than the desired pattern for consistency purposes.

Comment: try to format on lost focus event on text field

Comment: you have not used `type="submit"`. I think this is the issue.you can add a button to use it and see if it resolves the issue

Comment: @swetanshkumar - My input element is: <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>

Comment: Try `window.onload = function() {console.log(window.jQuery)}` to check if jQuery is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In form

```
<form id="update_business" method="post" action="assets/php/update_business.php">
```

In bottom the  of same page

```
$('#update_business').submit(function() {
    alert('here');
    return true; // Must
});
```

**Make sure jQuery is loaded on respective page**

Comment: This did not fire the event either. I am using the following CDN for jQuery: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: make sure your page loads that. this was working code on my existing. so im sure on it

Comment: make CDN library to offline. Improves loading speed

Comment: I verified that the page loads the jQuery by going to the debugger. Under my profile.php (the webpage that loads) it displays the entire markup (including the script) as it should be. Also, I had downloaded the CDN file, but to make sure it wasn't something wonky with the downloaded file, I used the online version.

Comment: does alert trigerd?

Comment: No. Also for safe measure I setup a breakpoint on the return, but it doesn't ever break.

Comment: OK, I've updated the post to include the form code (and jQuery) that I'm using when implementing your suggestion.

Comment: This successfully fires the event now, but the values of $('input[type="tel"]').text() are empty, presumably because the DOM elements haven't been created yet?

Comment: use `$('#phone').val()` and `$('#fax').val()`

Answer (score 0):

**Try this...**

```js
function onSubmit( form ){
  var data = JSON.stringify( $(form).serializeArray() ); //  <-----------

  console.log( data );
  return false; //don't submit
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onsubmit='return onSubmit(this)'>
  <input name='user' placeholder='user'><br>
  <input name='password' type='password' placeholder='password'><br>
  <button type='submit'>Try</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The form still submits and afterwards I receive the following error in the console: onSubmit is not defined.

Comment: @David Wrap the js code in document ready event and try again